# Como impedir que um link funcione em um elemento filho? (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery

Imagine o seguinte código abaixo:

```
<a id="link" href="/nova_pagina.php">
    <div id="abrir-nova-pagina"     >Linha_1</div>
    <div id="nao-abrir-nova-pagina" >Linha_2</div>
<a/>
```

Eu quero que o elemento a#link funcione quando eu clicar na primeira div e abra uma nova pagina e não quero que o link funcione quando eu clicar na segunda div.

Como posso fazer isso?

Vi alguns exemplos com jQuery usando o método stopPropagation() mas não funcionou.

Vejam abaixo:

```
$('a#link').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#nao-abrir-nova-pagina').on('click', function(event){
    alert('Funcionou!')
});
```

O que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: Jovem independente de qualquer coisa essa estrutura de HTML é muito errada, mesmo que vc consiga fazer funcionar... Um link é um link, "meio link" não faz sentido, tem algo errado ai...

Comment: Tá faltando o `event.preventDefault();`. Você parou a propagação, mas o link continua abrindo. Logo, vai precisar bloquear a ação padrão (abrir o link)...

Comment: @LipESprY nao entendi

Comment: Eu ia comentar justamente o que o @hugocsl falou. Não é melhor apenas a Linha_1 ser um link? A função da tag `a` é justamente fazer todo o conteúdo dela ser um link. Se cada linha se comporta de maneira diferente (uma é link, outra não é), então elas não deveriam estar dentro do mesmo `a`

Comment: `<a>
    <div>Linha_1</div><a/>` `<div>Linha_2</div>`

Comment: O `a` também está fechado errado. O correto seria `</a>` e não `<a/>`

Comment: Eu pensei em comentar sobre a estrutura do seu código, como fez o hugocsl. Também não entendi a necessidade de "não abrir um link ao clicar no link"... Normalmente usamos algum script associado a um link por completo. Mas, simplesmente respondendo sua pergunta, já tem uma resposta formulada pelo @Icaro Martins que condiz exatamente com meu comentário anterior.

Answer (score 0):

o `event.stopPropagation()` vai para a propagação do evento (no caso `onClick`) em outros elementos. 
*No exemplo abaixo se você comentar esse codigo ele, e clicar na `div#nao-abrir-nova-pagina` ele vai exibir o `alert('funcionou')` e depois o `alert(2)`.*

o `event.preventDefault()` faz ele não vai executar a ação padrão neste caso o `<a href>`

```js
$('a').on('click', function(event){
    alert(2);
});

$('#nao-abrir-nova-pagina').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); /// não propaga o click
    event.preventDefault(); /// não executa o <a href>
    alert('Funcionou!')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="/nova_pagina.php">
    <div id="abrir-nova-pagina"     >Linha_1</div>
    <div id="nao-abrir-nova-pagina" >Linha_2</div>
<a/>
```